# How to change data in a data table by using a drop down box

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to change the data that is displayed in a data table by using a drop down box where the user can select the status of the cars they want to view.The problem I am having is that the data is not changing when the status in the drop down has been changed. I am using django 1.8 Please see my code below.

Jquery / Data table

```
var datatable = $("#datatable").dataTable({
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
 $('#DropDown_Select').change(function () {
   status = $(this).val()
   $.ajax({
       "type": "GET",
       "dataType": 'json',
       "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       "url": sSource + "/" + status, //sending server side status and filtering table
       "data": aoData,
       "success": function (data) {

           fnCallback(data);
       }
   });

 });  
 }).columnFilter({
aoColumns: [
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
    { type: "text" },
]

});
```

Data table

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Engine size</th>
    <th>Max speed</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <td>Example car</td>
    <td>Example make</td>
    <td>1.4</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>Status</td>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Engine size</th>
    <th>Max speed</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tfoot>
```

Drop down box

```
<select id="DropDown_Select">
<option value="new">New</option>
<option value="old">Old</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables has an api you can use to filter and manipulate the data that is shown in the table. I did some dropdown filtering and the function looked something like this:

```
table.api().columns(<select column>).search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
```

The .draw(); call is important because any time you make changes to the data you want displayed by the plugin, you need to tell it to redraw.

When creating the dropdowns, I also found it useful to use the api to get all of the options included in the relevant column to generate the options for my dropdown. That code looks something like this:

```
table.api().columns(<select column>).column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
    select.append("<option value='" + d + "'>" + d + "</option>");
});
```